# Call Cost Calculator Python Exercise

Tags: python-3.x

I'm taking a python class for beginners. However, I'm struggling with the below:

**Description of exercise**

Write a program that computes the cost of a long-distance call. The cost of the call is
determined according to the following rate schedule:

• Any call started between 8:00 A.M. and 6:00 P.M., Monday through Friday, is
billed at a rate of $0.40 per minute.

• Any call starting before 8:00 A.M. or after 6:00 P.M., Monday through Friday, is
charged at a rate of $0.25 per minute.

• Any call started on a Saturday or Sunday is charged at a rate of $0.15 per
minute.

The input will consist of the day of the week, the time the call started, and the length
of the call in minutes.
The output will be the cost of the call.

Notes:

1. The time is to be input as 4 digit number, representing the time in 24-hour
   notation, so the time 1:30 P.M. is input as 1330
2. The day of the week will be read as one of the following three character string:
   ‘Mon’, ‘Tue’, ‘Wed’, ‘Thr’, ‘Fri’, ‘Sat’ or ‘Sun’
3. The number of minutes will be input as a positive integer.

For example, an execution could look like this:

Enter the day the call started at: Fri

Enter the time the call started at (hhmm): 2350

Enter the duration of the call (in minutes): 22

This call will cost $5.50

**The code I worked out:**

```
week = str(input("Enter the day call started at: "))
hour_started = int(input("Enter the time the call started at (hhmm): "))
duration = int(input("Enter the duration of the call (in minutes): "))

if(week == "Mon") or (week == "Tue") or (week == "Wed") or (week == "Thr") or (week == "Fri"):
    if(int(hour_started > 1800) and int(hour_started <= 2400)) or (int(hour_started < 800) and int(hour_started >= 0)):
     tarif2 = float(duration * 0.25)
     print("This call will cost " + '$' + '%.2f' % float(tarif2), sep="")
    if(int(hour_started >= 800) and int(hour_started <= 1800)):
     tarif3 = float(duration * 0.40)
     print("This call will cost " + '$' + '%.2f' % float(tarif3), sep="")
else:
    tarif1 = float(duration * 0.15)
    print("This call will cost " + '$' + '%.2f' % float(tarif1), sep="")
```

I know that my code doesn't import time module however, the task seems to not ask for such. The associated autograder is returning an error which seems to be not math but I/O related:

```
Test Failed: 'enter the day call started at:  this call will cost $5.50' != 'this call will cost $5.50'
```

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Comment: By the error it seems that the strings you entering in the `input()` are causing problem.

Comment: I thought this might be the case however, none of the changes to ```input()``` seem to do trick.

Comment: Is it possible to share the exercise, maybe I could help as there isn't any math error as you already pointed.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The exercise as described in my post is all I have. I then upload my code to an autograder which returns the "test failed..." line. Do you have any idea, how I can change the ```input()```?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with Array's?

Comment: What I think now is that, what if a call started at 1750 and continued for 20 mins, 10 mins will be billed at $0.4/m and 10 mins at $0.25/m. The above code doesn't calculate this way.

Comment: It's pretty difficult to map time with bare integers as 1 min after 1759 would be 1800 w.r.t time whereas it would continue to 1799 in integers. What if a call went over an hour. Maybe try to reach out the creator. If you get an answer please share it in the answer.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I was at this point too (splitting time up between different fees). The problem is; the example in the exercise shows no separation of fees - as 22 minutes start on Fri 2350, therefore two different fees would apply (10 min $0.25 and 12min $0.15)- however the displayed cost of call in the exercise doesn't take that into account. I wrote the code to reflect exactly the desired output - which it does...I will ask the teacher and forward any additional information.

Comment: Ok I got word from the instructor; code's correct, syntax's correct - it was due to the fact that I was missing a "the" -> the day THE call started at. Dang! I just read over it like a zillion times. Sorry! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is solved I'd like to point out some improvements you can start making to your code to make it look cleaner, as python is known to be.

```
week = input("Enter the day call started at: ").lower()
hour_started = int(input("Enter the time the call started at (hhmm): "))
duration = int(input("Enter the duration of the call (in minutes): "))

if week in ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thr', 'fri']:
    if (hour_started > 1800 and hour_started <= 2400) or (hour_started < 800 and hour_started >= 0):
        cost = duration * 0.25
        print(f"This call will cost ${cost}")
    elif hour_started >= 800 and hour_started <= 1800:
        cost = duration * 0.40
        print("This call will cost ${}".format(cost))
else:
    cost = duration * 0.15
    print("This call will cost " + '$' + '%.2f' % float(cost), sep="")
```

The above code would also work just fine. I had written this initially trying to solve the exercise, so thought of sharing it.

Happy Learning:)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering how to further simplify the code.